# Let $G=D_8$, $H = \langle b\rangle$ and $K = \langle a^{2}\rangle$. Find $N_G(H)$ and $N_G(K)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am very lost on this question.  I understand that $N_G(H)=\{g\in G\mid gHg^{-1}=H\}$.  However I am not sure what to do next.  Since b is the generator of this group I am assuming you put b where h is but I don't know what to do after this.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: The $ghg^{-1}=H$ does not make sense.

Comment: Try working with expressions of general elements in $D_8$. As you don't have too many of those, it should be easy to analyze.

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$ in terms of $D_8$?  Is $b$ the element that corresponds to a reflection and $a$ the element that corresponds to a rotation of $\frac{\pi}{4}$?

Comment: Yes @RobertShore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $a \in N_G(K)$ because $a$ commutes with $a^2$, and $\langle a \rangle$ is a maximal subgroup of $G=D_8$ (because it has index $2$), so to complete the determination of $N_G(K)$, all you need to know is whether $b^{-1}a^2b = ba^2b = a^{-2} \in K.$  It is, so $K \lhd G$.

To determine whether $g \in N_G(H$) for $g=b^ma^n$, note that $a^{-n}ba^n=ba^{2n} \in H \iff 4 \vert n$, and $(ba^n)^{-1}b(ba^n)=a^{-n}ba^n = ba^{2n} \in H \iff 4 \vert n$, so $N_G(H)=\{e, a^4, b, ba^4\}$.

Comment: For $b^{-1}a^2b = ba^2b = a^{-2}$ can you walk me through number theory wise how you got from each of those

Comment: $b^2=e$ so $b^2=b^{-1},$ and $ab=ba^{-1}$ so just walk the $b$ through the $a$s one at a time.

Comment: How does e=$b^{-1}$

Comment: @user710744 Sorry, should have been $b=b^{-1}$.